# Как загружать данные с Firebase, на Activity исходя из того какая кнопка была нажата на другом Activity?

Tags: activity, firebase, firebase-database, realm-database

Здравствуйте, у меня есть 2 Activity на одном RecyclerView на другом TextView. 
В  RecyclerView у меня 2 Itema при нажатии на которые активируется второе Activity, но данные загружаются так же, на сервере у меня подготовлены 2 разные информации, на данный момент я смог реализовать только загрузку 1 на обе кнопки, не могу различать их. Собственно в этом мой вопрос

Activity c RecyclerView .

```js
rivate RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Hotel> result;
private HotelAdapter adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = database.getReference("Hotel");

result = new ArrayList<>();

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.hotel_list);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager lin = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
lin.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lin);

adapter = new HotelAdapter(result);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

updateList();

}

private void updateList(){
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Hotel.class));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
Hotel hotel = dataSnapshot.getValue(Hotel.class);

int index = getItemIndex(hotel);

result.set(index, hotel);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

Hotel hotel = dataSnapshot.getValue(Hotel.class);

int index = getItemIndex(hotel);

result.remove(index);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
}
private int getItemIndex(Hotel hotel){

int index = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
if(result.get(i).key.equals(hotel.key)) {
index = i;
break;
}
}
return index;
}
}
```

Адаптер к этому Activiti

```js
    public class HotelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelAdapter.UserViewHotel>{

    private List<Hotel> list;

    public HotelAdapter(List<Hotel> list) {
    this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHotel onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new UserViewHotel(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_hotel , parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHotel holder, final int position) {
    Hotel hotel = list.get(position);

    holder.TvName.setText(hotel.name);
    holder.TvStar.setText("star:"+hotel.star + "");

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HotelViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(HotelViewActivity.EXTRA_POS, position);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
    }

    class UserViewHotel extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView TvName, TvStar;
    Button btPodrob;

    public UserViewHotel(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    TvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TvName);
    TvStar = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TvStar);
    btPodrob = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btPodrob);

    }
    }
    }
```

Activity с View

```js
public class HotelViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final String EXTRA_POS = "my_item_position";

private TextView TvDitalicHotel;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_view);

int my_item_position = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_POS);

TvDitalicHotel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvDitalicHotel);

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = database.getReference("DitalicHotel");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я внес изменение в строку .

`reference = database.getReference("DitalicHotel");`

изменил ее на

```
reference = database.getReference("DitalicHotel/" +  my_item_position);
```